# Jersey UniformInterfaceException trying to proxy to REST POST service

Tags: java, rest, post, firefox-addon, jersey

I keep receiving a 406 HTTP response when I try to execute code structured in this way.  I have tried restructuring the code and the inputs many times, but I still receive this error, and I've gotten to the point I don't even really know what to debug.  The exception seems to indicate that the `post()` method isn't supplying the `@FormParam`s in the desired format, but as you can see the `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` and the `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` do indeed match up.

I am using the Firefox add-on [HTTPRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/) to pass in the `@FormParam`s and have ensured that I am passing them in with the appropriate Content-Type (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).  I've run out of things to check.  Does anyone have any ideas?

---

*The Proxy Service*

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource service = client.resource(myURL);

Form form = new Form();
form.add("value1", value1);
form.add("value2", value2);
form.add("valueN", valueN);

String returnValue = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(String.class, form);
```

*The Actual Service*

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Path("/theService")
public String theService(
        @FormParam("value1") String value1,
        @FormParam("value2") String value2,
        @FormParam("valueN") String valueN) {

    String returnValue = null;

    /*
     * Do Stuff
     */

    return returnValue;
}
```

*The Exception*

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://theURL/theService returned a response status of 406
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:563)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:69)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:499)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[UniformInterfaceException](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/UniformInterfaceException.html) is just a catch-all exception with a poor name (it's named this because it's an exception that provides a uniform interface, no matter the error). It's basically an IOException thrown by anything in Jersey. The actual error is the [406 Unacceptable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error):

> The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.

Here you're saying that you accept `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`:

```
String returnValue = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(String.class, form);
```

But your service produces `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
```

Since your server can't produce any content that the client says it will accept, it returns a 406 error.

Most likely, you're meaning to set [`WebResource.type`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#type%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29), not `accept`:

```
String returnValue = service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(String.class, form);
```

Comment: So essentially... the Exception means exactly the opposite as what I thought it meant.  Haha.  The `accept()` method is dictating what the service should *return*, not what it should *accept*.

Comment: @Jeff Yes, `accept` sends the `Accept` header, which indicates the type of result the client will accept. To indicate the type of content you're sending, you need to call `type` (which sets the `Content-Type` header).

Comment: Well, thank you much, sir!  I definitely thought it was more complicated than a simple API misunderstanding. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same Exception after trying a number of different permutations on this solution.  Posting examples in the question above.

Comment: @Jeff Your last version should definitely work. Is it possible that the new code wasn't deployed on the server? I've had problems in the past where I needed to do a complete restart+redeploy to get things working correctly in Glassfish.

Comment: For debugging, it may be useful to sniff the traffic (with something like Wireshark) or remove the `@Produces` and `@Consumes` and log the type of the request on the server side.

Comment: Turns out the rest was an environment issue.  You were right about the core problem though. :)  Thank you much.

Comment: for exceptions on Jersey 2 see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360598/403999